# Add-Migration one column name is listed more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created all my model and then I added a new migration with `Add-Migration Initial`.

Adding migration created a migration file like expected in the migration folder, but for some reason it created a column called `client_id` twice. I am expecting to created a column called `client_id` with an integer type and not nullable.

I should note that the column `client_id` references the `Clients` model with a relation.

Here is how my model class look like

```
[Table("scripter_campaigns")]
public class Campaign
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)] 
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "The title must be greater than 5 characters  in length"), 
     MaxLength(200)] 
    public string name { get; set; }

     [Column(Order = 3)] 
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string layout { get; set; }

     [Column(Order = 4)] 
    [StringLength(200)] 
    public string call_list_server_name { get; set; }

     [Column(Order = 5)] 
    [StringLength(200)] 
    public string call_list_table_name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)] 
    public string status { get; set; }


    public string intro_url { get; set; }
    public string use_transfer { get; set; }
    public string route_callback_to { get; set; }
    public string call_list_database_name { get; set; }
    public int client_id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime? modified_at { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    //Initilize the default value

    public Campaign()
    {
        status = "Active";
        use_transfer = "No";
        route_callback_to = "Self"; 
    }

}
```

but it generated this code for the up() method in the migration script

```
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.scripter_campaigns",
        c => new
            {
                id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 200),
                layout = c.String(maxLength: 200),
                call_list_server_name = c.String(maxLength: 200),
                call_list_table_name = c.String(maxLength: 200),
                status = c.String(maxLength: 200),
                intro_url = c.String(),
                use_transfer = c.String(),
                route_callback_to = c.String(),
                call_list_database_name = c.String(),
                client_id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                created_at = c.DateTime(),
                modified_at = c.DateTime(),
                Client_id = c.Int(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.clients", t => t.Client_id)
        .Index(t => t.Client_id);
```

I do not understand where `Client_id = c.Int()` is coming from but it is causing me an issue when I try to update the database

Here is the error

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Client_id' in
>   table 'scripter_campaigns' is specified more than once.

Additionally, are Foreign keys in the database required for me to be able to build relation ship between my objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Client_id = c.Int()` is being created because of `public virtual Client Client { get; set; }`

This is because you need to do the following

```
[ForeignKey("Client")]
public int client_id { get; set; }
```

When you have the following in your entity class

```
public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
```

This way `[Table("scripter_campaigns")]` will know where the client_id is coming from.

**Update:** `[ForeignKey("Client")]` is instructing `public int client_id { get; set; }` to hold a value from `public virtual Client Client { get; set; }` object. Give that `scripter_campaigns` object is related to `Client` object.

Comment: May be I am not understanding what the keyword virtual does. what exactly does [ForeignKey("Client")] do?

Comment: @MikeA To my understanding, virtual allows for lazy loading. `[ForeignKey("Client")]` is saying that `public int client_id { get; set; }` will hold value from `public virtual Client Client { get; set; }` object

Comment: And is there a way not to use Foreign keys? Foreign keys will add an overhead that I like to getaway from

Comment: @MikeA when you call `public virtual Client Client { get; set; }` in your entity class, you are already using foreign keys. The annotation only avoids that duplicate column.

Comment: yes I understand. I am just trying to understand if there is a way to build the relation between 2 models without having to use/depend on foreign keys

Comment: If you dont want to use foreign keys, you can decorate your class with `[ComplexType]`. This should only be done for required:required relationships. `[ComplexType]` causes EF to write the data of Campaign into the same table as Client, and a complex type can not be `null`.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider thank you for that. Would you mind explaining more on how that work? an example would be great to understand how I would be able to use `[ComplexType]` to build relations between the models.

Comment: @MikeA You should ask a question with regards to `[ComplexType]`. Although, i am sure google will give you most of the information you need on the topic. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/gg193958.aspx

Comment: It really depends on the type of relationship you want to model. If one client can run many campaigns, `[ForeignKey("Client")]` is the way to go!